# Java AffineTransform

Tags: java, graphics2d, affinetransform

I have a project called Visually Data Structures.
I've been doing the project for almost a week but i stumble upon this problem.

I'm doing a lot of identity transformations in a single call of Graphics paint() method.

Expected Output: the DSNode draw() method should be called after identity transformation.
THE OUTPUT: it seems like the identity transformations are not working.

Here is my code:
This method is inside a class called viewPanel.

```
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        AffineTransform saveTransform = g2d.getTransform();
        final AffineTransform identity = new AffineTransform();
        g2d.setTransform(identity);
        g2d.clearRect(0, 0, this.WIDTH, this.HEIGHT);
        g2d.drawString(refVar, refVarX, refVarY);
        g2d.drawLine(arrowOfRefVarX, arrowOfRefVarY, arrowOfRefVarX+arrowOfRefVarLength, arrowOfRefVarY);
        g2d.drawLine(arrowOfRefVarX+arrowOfRefVarLength,arrowOfRefVarY,arrowOfRefVarX+arrowOfRefVarLength-5,arrowOfRefVarY-5);
        g2d.drawLine(arrowOfRefVarX+arrowOfRefVarLength,arrowOfRefVarY,arrowOfRefVarX+arrowOfRefVarLength-5,arrowOfRefVarY+5);
        DSNode temp = dsNode;
        while(temp!=null)
        {
            g2d.setTransform(identity);
            temp.draw(g2d);
            temp = temp.next();
        }
        g2d.setTransform(saveTransform);
    }
```

This method is inside another class called DSNode:

```
public void draw(Graphics2D g2d)
     {

    AffineTransform transform = g2d.getTransform();
    transform.translate(x,y);
    g2d.transform(transform);
    g2d.draw(rectangle);
    g2d.draw(rectanglePtrBox);
    g2d.drawLine(arrowX,arrowY,arrowX+arrowLength,arrowY);
    g2d.drawLine(arrowX+arrowLength,arrowY,arrowX+arrowLength-5,arrowY-5);
    g2d.drawLine(arrowX+arrowLength,arrowY,arrowX+arrowLength-5,arrowY+5);
    g2d.drawString(val,valX,valY);
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

*It seems like the identity transformations are not working.* Are the resulting objects drawn as if the transformations weren't used at all, or are they drawn at incorrect position?

Because in the second case, the cause might be that `transform.translate(x,y);` seems to change `transform` rather than creating new transformation, so if you draw multiple objects, the transformations would chain one after another.

So for object at [5,5] and [10,10], they would be drawn at [5,5] and [15,15]. This only a guess though.

Comment: Yes, it's like that. it will be drawn like that. i tried transform.setToIdentity() then use g2d.transform(transform). but still its like that.